# Input Date on the format MM/YY

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs, html, jsx

i want to let the user enter only date in this format MM/YY on the input date as the desciptive image:
[image]

As beginner Js and React developper, i allowed the user to show the date in the  MM/YY date form by adding "/".I'm searching about taping a regex pattern to enter the valide date or through other possiblity if it exists.

Here my React JS CODE:

```
import React from "react";

import "./styles.css";

export default class Card extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      displayMessageUser: "Enter the user name",
      displayMessageDate: "12/08",
      userName: "",
      validThru: "",
      validUser: {
        status: true,
        message: ""
      },
      validDate: {
        status: true,
        message: ""
      }
    };

    this.handleChangeName = this.handleChangeName.bind(this);
    this.handleChangeDate = this.handleChangeDate.bind(this);
  }

  handleChangeName(event) {
    var onlyTextRegex = /[^A-Za-z]/g;
    if (event.target.value.match(onlyTextRegex)) {
      this.setState({
        validUser: { status: false, message: "Tape only text" }
      });
    } else if (event.target.value.length > 20) {
      this.setState({ validUser: { status: false, message: "Max length 20" } });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        userName: event.target.value,
        valid: { status: true, message: "" }
      });
    }
  }

  handleChangeDate(event) {
    this.setState({
      validThru:
        event.target.value.substring(0, 2) +
        "/" +
        event.target.value.substring(2, 4),
      valid: { status: true, message: "" }
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { validUser } = this.state;
    const { validDate } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="displayCard">
        <div className="bgCreditCard">
          <div className="titleCard">
            <h1>Credit card</h1>
          </div>
          <div className="simCard">
            <img
              className="simCardImage"
              src="https://uploads.codesandbox.io/uploads/user/8f10ee4c-10fc-41b7-885a-4b795b293c1d/hh7c-chip.png"
              alt=""
            />
          </div>
          <div className="idCard">
            <h2 className="idCardNumber">7253 3266 5284 8621</h2>
          </div>
          <div className="userCard">
            <div className="userCardID">5422</div>
            <div className="userCardValidation">
              <div className="bloc1">
                Valid <br />
                thru
              </div>
              <div className="bloc2">
                month/year
                <br />
                <span>{this.state.validThru}</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="userCardDescription">{this.state.userName}</div>
          <div className="cardType">
            <img
              className="simCardImage"
              src="https://uploads.codesandbox.io/uploads/user/8f10ee4c-10fc-41b7-885a-4b795b293c1d/aFYl-visa.jpg"
              alt=""
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="inputInterface">
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder={this.state.displayMessageUser}
            onChange={this.handleChangeName}
          />
          {!validUser.status ? (
            <span style={{ color: "#ff0000" }}>{validUser.message}</span>
          ) : null}
          <input
            type="date"
            datatype="DD MM"
            placeholder={this.state.displayMessageDate}
            onChange={this.handleChangeDate}
          />
          {!validDate.status ? (
            <span style={{ color: "#ff0000" }}>{validDate.message}</span>
          ) : null}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: use https://nosir.github.io/cleave.js/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think regex would the best option here. For a valid date in this case you have to make sure

1. It's not expired. You can check today's date's year and month and make sure the input is before that date.
2. It's actually valid, for instance month is between 1 and 12.

`validateDate() {
    // Assuming variables inputYear and inputMonth are already defined and correspond to user's input.
    const todayDate = new Date()
    const todayYear = todayDate.getFullYear() // It gives you four digits so you might want to slice out the last two digits
    const todayMonth = todayDate.getMonth()
    if (!(inputMonth >= 1 && inputMonth <= 12)) return false
    if (inputYear > todayYear) return true
    else if (inputMonth > todayMonth) return true
    else return false
}`

Answer (score 0):

Just as an idea, hence it's about dates. You could use `moment` package and then check if its valid based on a format.

For example

`moment(yourDate, 'D/M', true).isValid()`